# How do I crop a geoJson file

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I have a geoGjon file that is quite big - it covers the whole world at a somewhat high level of detail. It takes a long time to download and render in d3.js. But I don't need a map of the whole world, I only need a section of it. How can I make this file smaller by cropping out all the data for parts of the world I don't need?

Comment: You can use a GIS program such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a simple bounding box you can use `ogr2ogr`:

`ogr2ogr -clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax] -f output.geojson input.geojson`

There is also an option to simplify, if you want to reduce the filesize further:

`ogr2ogr -simplify <tolerance> -clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax] -f output.geojson input.geojson`

see https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson), it significantly reduces the payload of transfering the GeoJSON information to the server. Also, you can remove sections of the original file and reduce the precision using the [command line options](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference). Regards,